# MonoDevelop - Arabic and other Unicode in code editor

Tags: unicode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I paste in some upper unicode, or even ansi like العربية

I get gibberish in MonoDevelop. I am using the MonoTouch framework.

Any idea how to get it to allow me to paste in Arabic, Chinese etc....

ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the default to Arial or tahoma, these are Unicode.