# MonoDevelop: Unicode file names

Tags: macos, unicode, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a folder of files with Arabic and Chinese names in Unicode. In MonoDevelop they do not render. IS there a way to have MonoDevelop render unicode?

Version 2.8 of MonoDevelop, Mac

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks perhaps like your gtk font doesn't have the arabic glyfs. Can you see arabic in the text editor?

Comment: I tried to paste some Hebrew characters inside MonoDevelop's editor and it did not show them properly. Still this could be GTK or font related.

Comment: see also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039332/monodevelop-arabic-and-other-unicode-in-code-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a known bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=830) that Pango, the font library used by MonoDevelop, does not support font fallbacks on MacOS. This has been fixed but the fix has not yet been shipped.

You may be able to work around this by configuring a custom font in MonoDevelop Preferences that includes all the glyphs you need.